# Adding, subtracting,dot product etc of vectors when they never co-incide at any point

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Suppose I have a vectorA=3â+1ê at a point (1,2) and another vectorB=-3â at a point (-1,0) meaning that both vectors never co-incide at any point in 2D

Could the vectors then be added, subtracted, operated with a dot or cross product ?

Comment: What do you mean by describing a vector as being "at a point $(1,2)$"? Vectors don't have a location.

Comment: I mean the tail of the vector starts at those points respectively

Comment: When you visualize a vector, such as $(2,3)$, you might picture an arrow with a certain magnitude and direction, but the location of that arrow you are visualizing doesn't matter. Any other arrow with the same magnitude and direction is an equally valid way to visualize the same vector, even if the arrow is drawn at a different location. Vectors don't have a location.

Comment: This is thoroughly discussed in several of the questions in the handy list of related questions at right, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136157/265466).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The definition of a vector do not consider the "base" point of where it emanates. So you generally just say that you have vectors $A=3\hat a+1\hat e$ and  $B=-3\hat a$.

These may be added, subtracted etc.